# How to add a list of strings in yaml file using argparser

Tags: yaml, parameter-passing, command-line-arguments, argparse

I would like to define a List of Strings in .yaml config (ss is attached).
For example: ['HNN','FRC']

I've created sth like that.

```
self.argParser.add_argument(
'--source.prefiks.list',
nargs = '*',
required=False,
default="",
help='Param used for definition of selected procesess')
```

[image: a snippet from the configuration file]

Answer (score 0):

I'm ok with this approach: It works properly.

```
self.argParser.add_argument(
    '--source.prefiks.list',
    type = lambda s: [str(item) for item in s.split(',')],
    required=False,
    help='Param used for definition of selected procesess')
```